# WSL open files in network drive

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've recently managed to access the shared network drive from WSL (windows 10 version 1903 OS Build 18362.356 and Ubuntu 18.04)
However when I try to open a pdf file for example, I get this error:

'\network\Shared\Documents\folder1\folder2'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

the command I am using to open is: 
cmd.exe /C start file,

which works for files in my C drive, how should I change this command to open network files? (which are in the S drive) I tried 
cmd.exe /S start file

but it didn't work.

Thank you!